# constexpr hash function

Tags: c++, c++17, hashcode, constant-expression

Here's a `constexpr` hash function, that will pack a string into the largest unsigned integral type available. So, what do you think?

```
#include <climits>

#include <cstdint>

#include <utility>

#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{

template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
constexpr T hash(char const* const s, std::size_t const N,
  std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept
{
  return ((T(s[I < N ? I : 0]) << ((I < N ? I : 0) * CHAR_BIT)) | ...);
}

}

template <typename T = std::uintmax_t>
constexpr T hash(char const* const s, std::size_t const N) noexcept
{
  return detail::hash<T>(s, N, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(T)>());
}

template <typename T = std::uintmax_t, std::size_t N>
constexpr T hash(char const(&s)[N]) noexcept
{
  return hash<T>(s, N - 1);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << (hash("a") == 'a') << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/KbPiWJc434xYLL3q

Answer (score 4):

Your code is too complex. With C++17, you can write more complex constexpr functions, so you don't need the variadic template tricks:

```
template <typename T = std::uintmax_t, std::size_t N>
constexpr T hash(char const(&s)[N]) noexcept
{
  T val{};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    val |= s[i] << (i * CHAR_BIT);

  return val;
}
```

Apart from that, this is a terrible hash function! The output is highly correlated to the input. It will also only hash up to `sizeof(T)` characters, so long strings with a common prefix might all get the same hash value.

Comment: take one more look at the code, what does `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(T)>()` do?

Comment: Ah, missed that!

Comment: The whole idea was to implement a perfect hash for small strings. We are going 128-bit, so it might not be such a bad idea. Even now, it's possible to enable a 128-bit uint by using `-std=gnu++17` That's 16 chars.

Comment: + even though they are not supposed to, looping `constexpr` functions tend to produce worse code than non-looping ones, when evaluated at run-time.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what the use case is of this hash function? Because I don't see the point in what basically is a `memcpy()` from a string into a suitably large `int`. I wouldn't call it hashing.

Comment: @Sliepen just avoiding a large chain of `if` comparisons or having to use a recognizer. Now, a `memcpy` in a `constexpr` is not possible yet and technically it is hashing, how else would I call it?

Comment: How oes this help you avoid a chain of if-comparisons? Please give a *concrete* example of how you intend to use this hash function.